# Adaptive header Microsoft Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, headers

For my work, I have a simple footer and header on each page which gives the title of the work, my group, my name, and the page number.

This is what the footer and header look like in portrait mode:
[image: Portrait]

However, my problem arises when I want a page with a different orientation to the first page. For example, if page one is portrait and page 2 is landscape, the header and footer on page two will look like this:

[image: Landscape]

As you can see, even though the second page is in landscape mode, the footer has automatically expanded to take the whole width but the header has remained the same size as it was in portrait mode.

*The Question*
Is there a way to make the header expand the whole width of the landscape page, like the footer has done automatically?

Comment: Use a right-align tab stop? [When a tab is not just a tab, part 2: right tabs](http://legalofficeguru.com/right-tabs-in-word/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Word wizard, so maybe there's a better way of doing this, but you can insert a section break at the end of your first page, set the new section to landscape, then you'll be able to edit the header/footer for the new section independently of the first section's header/footer.

To insert the section break, go to Page Layout tab | Page Setup group | click the triangle next to Breaks and under Section Breaks, choose Next Page.